# Nil Values When Iterating Through Arrays and Some Really Weird Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a rails newbie and am building an app. My current problem is trying to find the average time since the last purchase for each customer of an online store using the app, where we have data about their orders and their customers. The problem is that I'm getting an error that says "undefined method `src_created_at' for nil:NilClass." Right now I'm trying to do this only for customers that have purchased once, and leaving aside those that purchased multiple times.

Here's my code:

```
@customers = Customer.where(:identity_id => @identity.id)
@single_order_customers = @customers.where("orders_count = ?", 1)


days_since_array = []
@single_order_customers.each do |s|
one_order = Order.where(:identity_id => @identity.id, :src_customer_id => s.src_id)
the_date = one_order[0].src_created_at
purchase_date = the_date.to_date
days_between = (Date.today - purchase_date)
days_since_array << days_between
end

days = days_since_array.inject(:+)
@adslp = days / days_since_array.count
```

Thanks in advance. I can provide what customer and order data looks like if necessary. Any advice would help, even though I know this question is somewhat vague. I've tried some kind if and unless statements validating presence or nil values and they're not working.

Edit: 
Here's what's run in the console:

```
Order Load (123.0ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."identity_id" = 2 AND "orders"."src_customer_id" = '114863554'
NoMethodError: undefined method `src_created_at' for nil:NilClass
```

(The above is several orders successfully run and then breaking on the last I've shown.)

Last point: when I try, specifically, to find nil values for this purpose I don't find any.

```
Order.where(:identity_id => 2, :src_created_at => nil)
  Order Load (209.6ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."identity_id" = 2 AND "orders"."src_created_at" IS NULL
 => []
```

Comment: It looks like your query for `one_order` is returning an empty set, so `one_order[0]` is nil and src_created_at cannot be called on nil. I would also recommend reading up on rails debugging techniques, as those will help you greatly :)

Comment: The array "one_order" is very likely empty, and hence one_order[0] is nil.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I've edited it to indicate what the console was doing. cc: @FaithoftheFallen

Answer (score 0):

For your last point where you tried to find nil values, you are getting an empty array `[]` because your query returned an empty set (no records matched your query). Trying to access any index on an empty array in rails won't throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException, but will instead just return nil, which is where you are getting your nil from. You are expecting `one_order[0]` to be an order item, but it is instead nil.

The solution to your problem would be to make sure the Order you are searching for already exists in the database. You might want to check how your orders are being created, e.g. if you use Order.create(params[:order]), do you have any validations that are failing, etc. You can check the orders you have through the rails console; just run `Order.all`. There should be an Order that has an `identity_id` of 2 and `src_created_at` of nil for the last query you wrote to return an actual order in the set.

A quick fix for now would be to remove the extra query to set one_order and just get it from the customer:

```
...
@single_order_customers.each do |s|
    one_order = s.orders.first
    the_date = one_order.src_created_at
...
```

The extra query does not seem to be necessary. You have already filtered `@customers` by `identity_id`, and `src_customer_id` will definitely match `s.src_id` if you get orders by calling `s.orders`. Relationships should be set up correctly in the models so that a customer has_many orders. You mentioned that you are just starting with rails; I would highly recommend reading a tutorial for rails first to save yourself headaches like these in the future :)

Comment: You're right... it looks like there is a customer with 1 order which is empty. Is the way to fix this to add an unless/if statement validating presence of something before the .each statement? I just tried Array(@single_order_customers).each do |s| and @single_order_customers.try(:each) and still get the same error. I know the best way is to make the data perfect and it is in progress.

Comment: I edited my answer with how you can changed your code to get it working for now. @timmy_k